# Collapse and merge multiple Bootstrap navbars + sidemenu into one menu in mobile view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now. I have three Bootstrap 3 nav bars and a side bar (left menu). I would like to be able to merge all the menu items into one single menu in mobile view - so that I can style all the items as one slide-in menu in mobile devices.

I have created a [Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/nP2TVY54q6).

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jQuery to fetch all list items from the menus and append them to a new sidebar element which is used for the mobile slide-in menu.